# Using a search string read another string

Tags: powershell

Have a text file with so many contents like this:

```
AllocatedStorage           : 5
InstanceName               : snapshotinstance
SnapshotName               : Testsnapshot
SnapshotCreateTime         : 8/26/2015 8:34:47 AM

AllocatedStorage           : 5
InstanceName               : snapshotinstance
SnapshotName               : Backupsnapshot
SnapshotCreateTime         : 7/31/2015 8:00:00 AM
```

I need to read a specific string (which is read from another file) and if an exact match is found then I need to retrieve another string which is there within that block. For example, suppose if my search string is "7/31/2015 8:00:00 AM" then I need to retrieve SnapshotName for that specific block.

Is there a way to achieve this? Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
$File = Get-Content -Path 'S:\Test\File.txt'
$SearchTerm = '7/31/2015 8:00:00 AM'

$LineNr = $File | Select-String -Pattern $SearchTerm | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LineNumber
$File[$LineNr-2] | Split-String ':' | Select-Object -Last 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at your data and it looked like a good candidate for `ConvertFrom-StringData`. Lets use regex to split up your log file into is property groups and create PowerShell Objects from the data.

```psh
$snapshotData = (Get-Content -Raw "c:\temp\log.log")  -split '\s+(?=AllocatedStorage)' | ForEach-Object {
    # ConvertFrom-StringData needs name=value so we convert the colons.
    $Stringdata = $_-replace '\s+:','='
    New-Object PSObject -Property  $(ConvertFrom-StringData $Stringdata)
}
```

Using `\s+:` helps ensure we don't replace the colons inside the date strings. Now you can search the data and return what you are looking for.

```
$snapshotData | Where-Object{$_.SnapshotCreateTime -eq "7/31/2015 8:00:00 AM"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SnapshotName
```

Which would return: `Backupsnapshot`. Using custom objects can make it easier to get more complex data quickly.

Since we use `-Raw` you would need PowerShell 3.0 but could easily be replace with `Out-String` instead if need be.